# wcf/error: socket connection aborted

Tags: wcf

i just build a wcf service and i am getting the following error?:

> The socket connection was aborted.
>   This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive
>   timeout being exceeded by the remote
>   host, or an underlying network
>   resource issue. Local socket timeout
>   was '00:00:59.2790

Comment: what is the code in your wcf service?

Comment: 60 seconds is the default timeout, so it looks like your WCF service isn't returning within that time. Slow Database query, infinite loop, debug tracepoint ... could be anything?

Comment: Turn on WCF tracing on both client and server and check inner error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: i tried to make the resultset of the wcf service smaller and this works fine. How can i configure the service to make it suitable for larger messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing readerQuota and MaxReceiveMessageSize of the binding. If you're using default binding configuration, you'd need to create a binding configuration and apply it on endpiont. Please find MSDN articles on topics,

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733051.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/09/20/how-to-change-reader-quota-values-programmatically.aspx